# Bootstrap input group inside table <td> tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue when trying to add bootstrap input-group-addon to the input field that is inside the table `<td>` tag. When adding all needed classes there is some space between a sign and input field.

```
<td>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
        <%= text_field_tag "variables[#{@home_price_budget.name}]", params.fetch(:variables, {}).fetch(@home_price_budget.name, ''), value: @home_price_budget.default.to_i, class: "form-control", type: 'number' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Result:
[image]

What is the solution for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Try changing `<div class="input-group-addon">$</div>` to `<span class="input-group-addon">$</span>`

Comment: @ksarunas this leads to the same result..

Comment: have you inspected the element to make sure a right margin isnt being applied to the addon? or even a left margin to the input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are not applying a margin to the form input, that would create this problem if you are doing it on a global CSS scale (all input elements)

here is a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gr909oft/)
showing how a simple margin can effect this.

html:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input margin" aria-  describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    margin-left: 7px;
}
```

Comment: while inspecting the element I found what was the reason of my issue. So, the reason is I that applied `border-spacing: 10px;` for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'span' instead of 'div', modify your HTML as:

```
<td>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <%= text_field_tag "variables[#{@home_price_budget.name}]", params.fetch(:variables, {}).fetch(@home_price_budget.name, ''), value: @home_price_budget.default.to_i, class: "form-control", type: 'number' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: try after removing "div" with class 'form-group'

Comment: again the same result